# Having trouble proving change of variables from integral of differential forms.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

From what I understand, the integral of a differential form $dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^k$ on $[a^1,b^1]\times\cdots\times [a^k,b^k]$ is defined by

$$
\int_{[a^1,b^1]\times\cdots\times [a^k,b^k]} dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^k := \int_{a^k}^{b^k}\cdots\int_{a^1}^{b^1} dx^1 \cdots dx^k
$$

Where the right is $k$ repeated Riemann integrals.

I am having trouble proving the change of variables rule for Riemann integrals using differential forms. I don’t see where the absolute sign would appear. Here’s what I have so far...

Let

$$
\phi : [p^1,q^1]\times\cdots\times [p^k,q^k] \to [a^1,b^1]\times\cdots\times [a^k,b^k], (t^1, \dots , t^k) \mapsto \left( \phi^1 (t^1,\dots ,t^k), \dots , \phi^k (t^1,\dots ,t^k)\right)
$$
be bijective and its total derivative bijective, too.

Then

$$
\int_{a^k}^{b^k}\cdots\int_{a^1}^{b^1} dx^1 \cdots dx^k = \int_{[a^1,b^1]\times\cdots\times [a^k,b^k]} dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^k 
\\
= \int_{[p^1,q^1]\times\cdots\times [p^k,q^k]} \phi^* \left(dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^k\right)
= \int_{[p^1,q^1]\times\cdots\times [p^k,q^k]} det( D\phi ) \,\,\, dt^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dt^k
$$

where $D\phi$ denotes the total derivative of $\phi$ to $t^1,\dots , t^k$.

I feel like the next step is to turn this into a Riemann integral but then there wouldn’t be an absolute sign on that determinant.

Comment: Looks like an orientation issue.

Comment: Hence, you've uncovered a hidden assumption. Usual (and lets just say sensable) integration is only for orientable pieces i.e the jacobian of the transition maps have position determinant i.e the change of variables map has positive determinant; hence there's no need for the absolute value.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood Can you please elaborate further?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f^1,...,f^k$ be smooth $\mathbb{R}$-valued functions on $M$ corresponding to a diffeomorphism $f$. Then we have,

\begin{align*} (df^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge df^k)(v_1,...,v_k)&= \sum_{\sigma \in S_k} \textbf{sgn}(\sigma) \ df^1(v_{\sigma(1)}) \cdots df^k(v_{\sigma(k)}) \\ & = \textbf{det}[df^i(v_j)]_{i,j} \end{align*}

where the last equality follows from the definition of the determinant. Hence, if we redefine the vectors $v_i = \partial_i:= \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ then $(df^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge df^k)(\partial_1,...,\partial_k) = \textbf{det}[df^i(\partial_j)] = \textbf{det}\left[\frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j}\right]_{i,j}$. We will now use this fact.

- On charts $(U, \textbf{x})$ and $(V, \textbf{y})$ of $M$, the overlap map $f(\textbf{x}) = \textbf{y} = \begin{pmatrix} f^1(\textbf{x})& \cdots & f^n(\textbf{x}) \end{pmatrix}^T$ is a diffeomorphism. Moreover we have $y^i = f^i$ and the following chain of identities,

\begin{align*} dy^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dy^n (\partial_{i_1},...,\partial_{i_n}) &= \textbf{sgn}(\sigma) \ dy^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dy^n(\partial_1,...,\partial_n) \\ \\ &= \textbf{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot  \textbf{det}\left[\frac{\partial f^i}{\partial x^j}\right]_{i,j} \\ \\ &=  \textbf{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \textbf{det}\left[\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}\right]_{i,j} dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n( \partial_1,...,\partial_n) \end{align*}

Consider now the problem in finding the area of $X = U \cap V$. Recalling that the signature of permutation is $\pm 1$, then by the above identity and the fact that $dy^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dy^n$ and $dx^1 \wedge \cdots dx^n$ are volume forms on $X$ we have,

\begin{align*} \int_X \textbf{sgn}(\sigma) \ dy^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dy^n  &= \int_X \textbf{sgn}(\sigma) \cdot \textbf{det}\left[\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}\right]_{i,j} dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n \\ \\ & = \int_X \ \left|\textbf{det}\left[\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}\right]_{i,j}\right| \ dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n \end{align*}

However, by the change of variables formula $\int_X dy^1  \cdots dy^n=\int_X  \left|\textbf{det}\left[\frac{\partial y^i}{\partial x^j}\right]_{i,j}\right| \ dx^1  \cdots  dx^n $

- Hence if the Jacobian of the transition charts are always positive then $M$ is Riemann Integrable. If you know the definition of orientable i.e smoothly varying frame then one can show that this property of the transition charts is equivalent to $M$ being orientable.

Geometrically one can reason this using the fact that the determinant gives the oriented volume of the parallelepiped spanned by the columns vectors.

- In this case the two sets of column vectors are the ones in the coordinates of the cotangent basis $dy^1,...,dy^n$ and the other in $dx^1,...,dx^n$. Let's call these $d \textbf{x}$ and $d \textbf{y}$ for short. Then $d\textbf{x}(v_1,...,v_n)$ and $d\textbf{y}(v_1,...,v_n)$ projects the parallelepiped spanned by $v_1,...,v_n$ onto the $(x_1,...,x_n)$ and $(y_1,...,y_n)$ coordinate planes and computes the volume. Hence, both should return the same signed volume.

It's in this projection that the sign issued is singled out. Why?

- Think of projecting the plane $x_3 = 1$ onto the $x_1,x_2$-plane which is $x_3 = 0$. If we orient  the $x_1,x_2$-plane with the counterclockwise orientation then $x_3$ is the usual "up" i.e toward our normal sky. However, if we choose the clockwise orientation, $x_3$ points toward the ground and this is understood to be "up". The signature handles this and recognizes that to project onto this version of the $x_1,x_2$-plane (which is the $y_1,y_2$-plane) we'll have to multiply be a negative since the overlap map is,

  $$f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = (y_1(x_1,x_2,x_2),y_2(x_1,x_2,x_3), y_3(x_1,x_2,x_3))$$

where $y_1= x_1,y_2 = x_2$ and $y_3 = -x_3$ i.e in the frame induced by the coordinate system $\textbf{y}$, the plane $x_3 = 1$ is $x_3 = -1$.

Comment: Are the $\partial_{i_k}$’s in the start of your first bullet point meant to be $\partial_{\sigma(k)}$?

Comment: Yes, that's the correlation between the two i.e $i_k = \sigma(k)$.

Comment: Let me make a crucial edit and comment!

Comment: Okay, now it's all correct. I'm so sorry.

Comment: In your first bullet point, I don’t understand why you are permuting the basis vectors. Is it purely to get a signature so you can then turn the determinant into its absolute value?

Comment: Yup. You can either do that or use $\sigma^{-1}$ on $\{1,...,k\}$ when you want to show the relation going in the other direction i.e when evaluating $dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n (\partial_1,...,\partial_k)$.

Comment: I'll direct you to this book, Loring Tu's Introduction to Manifolds. Look at the exterior algebra section.

Comment: The whole idea is that the exterior algebra is so cleverly put together that the order presented in a form, determines the orientation not the order of the entries i.e the signature should always $1$. Orientation being determined by the entries is that for the vector space, but the manifold is oriented by the form and these two are made to agree in the exterior algebra. The vector space orientation is masked in the entries on evaluation i.e $\omega(v_1,...,v_n)$, okay, what's the orientation? It's not necessarily $[v_1,...,v_n]$.

Comment: I shall have a look at that book you suggested. I’ll come back after I’ve lined up what you said with the content of the book. Thanks for the help so far.